# How can I add a button at the end of a listView?

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1

Iwould like to add a button at the end of a listView in the same way as the bing apps do (see picture for example).

I looked for hours in google and in the microsoft documentation but canøt find anything that can give me an idea of how to do this.

Did anyone achieved this?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run that app (Health & Fitness), then run Visual Studio and use Debug > Attach to Process, you can open the DOM Explorer and examine how that UI is implemented.

What you'll see in this case is that it's not using a ListView at all, but rather it's own custom control that's just based on a CSS grid. That is, just because there's a grid-like view doesn't mean it's a ListView. You can always use straight HTML/CSS layout to achieve these sorts of things, which is all that's happening here. As such, it just makes separate div's for those two "More" elements.

Now if you *do* want to use a ListView, there are a few things you can do. First of all, if you want to render any item in a ListView differently than others, you have to make sure to use a different template. What this means is that you use an item rendering function rather than a declarative template, which then enables you to examine the item data and programmatically decide what kind of rendering to perform.

Second, if you want to have items of different sizes, then you need to use cell spanning. In Windows 8.0/WinJS 1.0 this is a property of the GridLayout. In Windows 8.1/WinJS 2.0 you instead use the CellSpanningLayout.

I have all the details for both rending functions and cell spanning written up in Chapter 7 of my [second edition preview of *Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript,*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2) which is a free ebook from Microsoft Press so it doesn't cost you anything. :)

Comment: Brockschmidt - MFS Thanks for your tips. I have your book first edition. I'll just get the second and read it more thoroughly.

Comment: In the bing apps they have the "More" button everywhere. And they use those apps to demo the functionalities of the listView, do you mean they never used a listview in the bing apps?

Comment: They might use ListView in some places, but the Bing apps generally provide consumer-value functionality are weren't necessarily built to showcase controls (the SDK samples do that). ListView, after all, is a collection of a bunch of divs with behavior attached to it, so there's nothing particularly magical there. The Bing apps then use whatever controls work for their scenarios, whether they be WinJS or custom controls.