# When are the items in a listview available in the dom?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I have a page with a listView.
I need to read the position of the last item in the listView once is loaded, but I can't find the right moment or event to do it. Basically I can't find a way to determine if all the items are loaded in the list.

This is my ready function, as you can see I can find when the listView load is complete, but it seems like even at that point the items are not available in the DOM:

There is only one list in the page.

```
ready: function (element, options) {

    //now the onloadingstatechanged evenet for the list
    var listView = element.querySelector(".itemslist").winControl;
    listView .onloadingstatechanged = function (args) {
        if (args.srcElement === listView .element && listView .loadingState === "complete") {

            debugger;

            /* THIS LINE SHOULD WORK IF THE ITEMS WERE LOADED, items IS INSTEAD null*/
            var items = element.querySelector(".itemslist .win-itemsblock");

            listView .onloadingstatechanged = null;
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the listView in my DOM object when the app stop at the `debugger;` instruction:

[image]

and here is the listView in my DOM object after the program run til the end:

[image]

Comment: What is the intent behind trying to get to rendered elements of the list view. typically, it is good to use binding and template.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the position of the last element in the listView so I can attach a custom button at the end of the list. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546995/how-can-i-add-a-button-at-the-end-of-a-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type debugger; in the event body and then inspect the DOM using the DOM Inspector and see if your ListView has been fleshed out. You're right that when the loading state is complete you should have access to the DOM elements, so perhaps there's something wrong with your selector.

Comment: I updated my question with a view of the DOM object inside the loadingstate complete event, and a view of what is the listView after that. I can't find what is the event that fires after all the win-container objects are loaded. You can see there if the selector is fine.

Comment: maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm loading data asynchronously, but that should not affect the event

Comment: I think your problem is that you're disabling the onloadingstatechanged event after its first run. It needs to run each time items are loaded. When it loads its first time it has no data in the ListView to load. Remove your `listView .onloadingstatechanged = null;` line and see if your breakpoint eventually reports a non-null value for items.

Comment: you are right! I was doing it because I get the loadingState === "complete" twice, but it is in fact only the second time that I have elements loaded in the list. thanks very much